# How to export HAR file from Firefox without opening the dev tools

Tags: firefox

I want to analyze what a webpage does and loads when I interact with it, i.e. export a HAR file, but unfortunately, the page somehow detects it when dev tools are opened (even if opened in another window) and then stops working entirely.

Is there any way to capture and export a HAR file without opening the dev tools?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's an enterprise web application with almost no user support.

Comment: Well, the HAR functionality is dependent on Devtools, so it's not possible to invoke it without opening them.

Comment: But maybe it's still possible to trick the web app, if it detects that the Devtools are open through a debugger statement. A debugger statement acts as a breakpoint if the devtools are open, otherwise it does nothing. So all you need is to disable the breakpoints. Select the debugger panel and click the icon next to the debugger settings. Then load the web app.

Comment: As far as I can see, the page does that quite excessively (if I just want to "step through" these statements, I never finish, maybe every loop in the page has one). But even if I deactivate the breakpoints altogether, there must be something else in there, because the page never finishes loading if the dev tools are open and I cannot interact with it.